# Команда awk для сравнения двух файлов

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, awk

Хотелось бы разобраться в следующей конструкции:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a){print $1}' 1.txt 2.txt
```

---

Вот то, что я, надеюсь, правильно понял:

```
{a[$1];}
```

это заполнение массива **a**  первыми  словами каждой строки из файла 1.txt

```
!($1 in a){print $1}
```

печатать первые слова каждой строки файла 2.txt в 3.txt, если НЕ найдем их в массиве **a**

Но что в `NR==FNR{a[$1];next}` именно значит  `NR==FNR` и `next`?

Буду благодарен за объяснение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В скрипте `NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a){print $1}` два правила:

1. `NR==FNR{a[$1];next}` - это правило выполняется для всех строк, для которых номер строки в файле (переменная `FNR`) совпадает с номером строки во всех файлах (переменная `NR`). Фактически, это условие означает "строка из первого файла". Переменная `$1` - это первое слово в строке. `a[$1]` создаёт в массиве `a` запись с ключом `$1`. `next` означает, что нужно остановить обработку текущей строки и перейти к следующей. То есть второе правило не будет применяться для строк из первого файла. Первое правило создаёт множество слов, с которых начинаются строки в первом файле.
2. `!($1 in a){print $1}` - это правило выполняется при условии `!($1 in a)`, то есть для тех строк, в которых первое слово не встречается среди ключей массива `a`. Действие этого правила печатает первое слово соответствующих строк.

Итого, данный скрипт печатает начальные слова строк из второго-третьего-последующих файлов, с которых не начинались строки из первого файла.